# Setting up a community server for OR-enthusiasts

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, discord

I am thinking it would be a great idea to set up an OR Discord server for people who are studying or working with the methods for operations research. I myself study that field at university, but I haven't spoken to many people who have applied those methods in the real world. I would like to learn from those people and ask questions directly.

If you're not familiar with Discord: It is basically a platform where people can ask questions and talk directly in voice rooms with each other without the necessity of setting up a call and people can freely join a room and join a discussion at any time.

The idea is inspired by the big IT/programmer community where a lot of like-minded people meet online. Talk about interesting topics and help each other when it comes to technological issues.

Here is the server I set up: https://discord.gg/k5AtFccjne.
It is possible to assign roles to active community members and make them moderators.

Comment: I just joined the server. It's not a bad idea, but I don't know how many people will log in regularly. I'm not sure how often I will.

Comment: I already added I have various community related to engineering, data science and artificial intelligence in discord maybe I can share your server for students interested in OR. I like your idea because I know few people working or student OR field. If we have this discord for fast response and discuss stuff of or.stackexchange is also nice.

Comment: @rubengavidia0x sharing would help yes.

Comment: With the server being more active now I think it's a good time to get more people from here to join.