# Discord Presentation #1: Container Shipping (Tonight 20:00 GMT)

Tags: discussion, discord

One of our users [Eddiee](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/4380/eddiee) is giving a talk on Container Shipping Network Design this evening (20:00 GMT):

- Basic ideas of some solution methods will be explained:
  Genetic algorithms, Tabu search, decomposition approaches

on our [Operations Research Discord server](https://discord.gg/3KmeE8pm?event=931987427340456036) (for details see [this meta post](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/setting-up-a-community-server-for-or-enthusiasts)).

All welcome to join!