# Discord Presentation #2: Vehicle Routing and Just-in-Time Systems (Feb 13th, 19:30 GMT)

Tags: discussion, discord

<sub>Previous presentation: [Discord Presentation #1: Container Shipping (Tonight 20:00 GMT)](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/discord-presentation-1-container-shipping-tonight-2000-gmt)</sub>

---

This Sunday (19:30 GMT) there will be a presentation on the implementation of VRP-type problems and just-in-time systems by [Eddiee](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/4380/eddiee).

The link to join the event is here: https://discord.gg/pKGRghxg?event=940516392237670430. As always, everyone is welcome.